# jquery $.getJSON repeats X times

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm having trouble recreating the issue in jsbin without giving away project-specific details (I'm using JSON from an API), but I'm running into an issue that I can't seem to get around, and would really appreciate any help or insight.

I start with the following markup:

I have a blank unordered list.

```
<ul id="results-list">
  <!-- it is blank for now, and will be populated via jQuery -->
</ul>
```

And also an input.

When that input has been submitted, I run some code to populate #results-list with data, based on a JSON response. All's well. In that population of the data, I embed links that go nowhere, to make it like a sidebar navigation (user clicks on a link, and the main content area's content changes accordingly). This works fine the first time around.

Then, I've got an anonymous function running inside of .live() for clicking on those links in #results-list.

```
$("#results-list a").live('click', function(){
    // populate the main content area with the correct information.
});
```

Okay, so that works just perfectly the first time around. Once the user changes what's in the input, and resubmits the form, all of the items in the main content area change accordingly, but there are two of them. If they resubmit the form again, there are three. And so on.

So, the main content stuff is duplicated X times, with X being the number of times the form has been submitted.

I realize this is a somewhat vague question, but I wanted to see if anyone had any pointers as to what may be going on? This is all happening within a normal `$.getJSON` method call.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you're calling the `live` function after each post?

Comment: What have you done to diagnose the problem for yourself? Have you checked the response from your `$.getJSON` call and verified you're getting what you think you should be for each call? Knowing where the problem is in your code will make it much easier to fix it.

Comment: ...and that was it. I feel very stupid. Thank you Graham! If you'd like to make your comment an answer, I'll upvote & mark it correct!

Comment: so are you saying depending on how many times the page has been refreshed then a click on one of the items in your results-list is running the population function that same number of times?

Perhaps do $("#results-list a").die(); to ensure that no events are already attached to those list items.

Comment: Hey everyone, thank you for posting the comments! Graham brought up the point that I had the live function in the wrong spot, and that fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call the `live` function after each post, jQuery will just keep adding event handlers to the DOM, so the handler will get called multiple times. To get round this, either just call the `live` function once, or if you have to set up event handlers after each post use `unbind` and then a `bind` function (i.e. `bind` or something more specific like `click`).