# $.getJSON Repeating and Incrementing (JSONP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jsonp, getjson

My situation is very similar to what is spelled out here:

[jquery $.getJSON repeats X times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675898/jquery-getjson-repeats-x-times)

However I am not using the `live` function so his solution did not make it apparent to my why I'm having this issue.

My issue is that the first time I call the webservice it is only called once. The user continues on and finishes their process and returns to the main menu. The second time the service is called twice. The third time: three times and so on.

The service is called from a click event on a site that is a **"one page"** site using jQuery `show` and `hide` to navigate. *(The site is made for a very small screen)*.

**Pardon how wonky this is. I understand it that it's a bit roundabout.**

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    var buttonValue = $(this).attr('value');
    if (buttonValue === 'YES') {
        $.answer('Y');
    } else {
        $.answer('N');
    }
});
```

Which calls:

```
(function ($) {

    'use strict';

    $.extend({

        answer: function(SEL) {

            if (SEL === 'Y') {

                $('#label').html('Answer? <strong>Y</strong>');
                $('#answerPage').hide();
                $.example('Y');

            } else {

                $('#label').html('Answer? <strong>N</strong>');
                $('#answerPage').hide();
                $.example('N');

            }

        }

    });

}(jQuery));
```

Here we populate and append the results:

```
(function ($) {

    'use strict';

    $.extend({

        example: function(SEL) {
            var i,l,
            url = 'http://www.example.com?flag=' + SEL + '&callback=?';

            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                for (i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i = i + 1) {
                    $('#page').append('<p>data[i].Name</p>);
                }
            });

            $('#page').show();
        }

    });

}(jQuery));
```

I noticed that on every request the callback name is unique. IE:

callback=jQuery11020049298197496682405_1396904089952&_=1396904089953
callback=jQuery11020049298197496682405_1396904089945&_=1396904089951

**EDIT: The data returned:**

```
jQuery110207106537006329745_1396907300225([
   {
      "Code":1,
      "Name":"VISUAL",
      "DefaultDueIn":15,
      "EmailSubject":"",
      "EmailContent":"",
      "InStore":true,
      "ReturnStatus":null
   },
   {
      "Code":2,
      "Name":"ALTERATIONS",
      "DefaultDueIn":15,
      "EmailSubject":"",
      "EmailContent":"",
      "InStore":true,
      "ReturnStatus":null
   },
   {
      "Code":3,
      "Name":"HOLD FOR RTV",
      "DefaultDueIn":30,
      "EmailSubject":"",
      "EmailContent":"",
      "InStore":true,
      "ReturnStatus":null
   },
   {
      "Code":4,
      "Name":"MARKETING",
      "DefaultDueIn":15,
      "EmailSubject":"",
      "EmailContent":"",
      "InStore":true,
      "ReturnStatus":null
   },
   {
      "Code":5,
      "Name":"EVIDENCE",
      "DefaultDueIn":90,
      "EmailSubject":"",
      "EmailContent":"",
      "InStore":true,
      "ReturnStatus":null
   }
])
```

**The page contents are reset once the user returns to the main menu**

```
$('#page').html('');
```

I can see in the network logs that the request is run more than one time, incrementing each time.

Are there spurious processes continuing to run until a browser reload kills them? How can I manage this?

Comment: Here's my guess.  Does the `data` that you're getting back from the `getJSON()` call and appending to `#page`, have a script tag in it?  Does that script install any event handlers such that you end up with an increasing number of the same event handlers that all run whenever you click?

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause this behavior other than you including javascript in the text being returned from the server within the ajax call made in $.example.

Comment: I've updated my data with the contents of the JSON object. No script tag is returned and appended. The append to #page is an example. I'm actually pulling data from the name and code node and applying their value to buttons.

Comment: Given your update, i see no reason for the request to be sent twice unelss you are executing the first snippet of code twice.

Comment: That's the thing. It only happens twice on the second time. Three times on the third time... etc... I'm finding it very odd.